# Complex dimension of zeros of vanishing ideal vs real dimension

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a subset of real points and $I(S)$ be the vanishing ideal of $S$ in $\mathbb{R}[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$. Is $\dim V_{\mathbb{R}}(I(S)) = \dim V_{\mathbb{C}}(I(S))$? I.e., is the dimension of the real zero set of $I(S)$ equal to the dimension of the complex zero set of $I(S)$?

I think this is true, but I can't prove it rigorously. Any comments or answers are appreciated.

Comment: Yes, this is true. The point is that the vanishing ideal of the set $S' = V_{\mathbb{R}}(I(S))$ is also $I(S)$, so $S'$ must contain a smooth point on each irreducible component of the variety $V$ defined by $I(S)$. Now use the fact that if an irreducible real variety contains a smooth real point then the dimension of the set of real points is the same as the (algebraic) dimension of the variety.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree. Consider $S=\{x^2+y^2+1\}$.

Comment: @DonuArapura: the ideal of vanishing of that set over R is the zero ideal.  The variety of this ideal over the complex numbers is still empty.  Pew is starting with a set of points, not a variety.

Comment: OK, I guess I didn't read the question carefully.

Comment: @naf thank you. Do you have a reference why $S’$ must have a smooth point on each irreducible component?

Comment: The reason for that is that $S'$ (in fact even $S$) is Zariski dense in $V$ and the singular points form a proper subvariety (of each irreducible component).

Comment: @naf Do you mean $V = V_{\mathbb{C}}(I(S))$? If this is the case, then $S’$ is Zariski dense in $V$ means $\dim (V) = \dim(S’)$, which is what we want to prove, so is this a cyclic proof?

Comment: By $V$ I mean the real variety associated to the ideal $I(S)$ which you can think of as the complex points. For a real variety there are two different dimensions, the dimension of the set of real points and the dimension as a variety and what I am using is that for a smooth real variety these dimensions are the same if the set of real points is non-empty.